# Standard representation of FFT of an Image?

Tags: image-processing, frequency, dft

**Statement 1 :** When we take DFT of an image matrix, we get DFT co-efficient matrix. What does  the DFT Co-efficients tells about the image? (For example, take the 1st co-eff in the DFT matrix, what does it tells us ?)

**Statement 2:** In a DFT matrix, we have low frequency components on the top left corner of the matrix and the frequency will be getting increase as we move down and we have high frequency in the bottom right corner. Is this statement correct ? Correct me if I am wrong.

I couldn't able to understand the following image (**which contradicts my statement 2 (I think so )**) , can anyone explain this pls?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For real data, the result of an FFT is conjugate symmetric, so all but quadrant A is often ignored as redundant info.  Statement 2 seems to be about just quadrant A.

Comment: What they mean by standard & optical representation ?